# Get all values from table group by one field

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

I have a table "products", it contains value like below.

```
column-a     column-b     column-c      column-d   ....
   1023         57         value1        value2    ....
   1024         58         value3        value4    ....
   1025         58         value5        value6    ....
   1026         57         value7        value8    ....
   1027         59         value9        value10   ....
   1028         60         value11       value12   ....  
   1029         59         value13       value14   ....
```

From this table I want to display result like below group by column-b.

Array
(

```
 [0] => stdClass Object
    (
      [column-a] => 1023
      [column-b] => 57
      [column-c] => value1
      [column-d] => value2
      .
      .
      .
    )
    [1] => stdClass Object
    (
      [column-a] => 1024
      [column-b] => 58 
      [column-c] => value3
      [column-d] => value4
      .
      .
      .
    )
    [2] => stdClass Object
    (
      [column-a] => 1027
      [column-b] => 59
      [column-c] => value9
      [column-d] => value10
      .
      .
      .
    )

    [3] => stdClass Object
    (
      [column-a] => 1028
      [column-b] => 60
      [column-c] => value11
      [column-d] => value12
      .
      .
      .
    )

    [4] => stdClass Object
    (
      [column-a] => 1026
      [column-b] => 57
      [column-c] => value7
      [column-d] => value8
      .
      .
      .
    )
    [5] => stdClass Object
    (
      [column-a] => 1025
      [column-b] => 58
      [column-c] => value5
      [column-d] => value6
      .
      .
      .
    )
    [6] => stdClass Object
    (
      [column-a] => 1029
      [column-b] => 59
      [column-c] => value13
      [column-d] => value14
      .
      .
      .
    )
```

)

How to select all table values from table group by column-b.

I have tried like below, but its displaying values only one time of column-b

```
SELECT * FROM products GROUP BY column-b;
```

Someone help to retrieve all data with the same. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the query as follows:

```
SELECT column-a,column-b,GROUP_CONCAT(column-c SEPARATOR ' , '),GROUP_CONCAT(column-d SEPARATOR ' , ') FROM products GROUP BY column-b
```

It will return the array of records with distinct column-b values with multiple values for column-c and column-d